# Smartedit Attribute of type Product don't editable in editor

Tags: java, widget, content-management-system, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a CMS Component (so it extends SimpleCMSComponent), whose editing works in smartedit. The component has a Product attribute to select a single product from the catalog version. Although the component editing form is visible in smartedit, no edit widget is visible for the attribute above, but only the word "Actega Product Catalog" and below it the name of the attribute.

Let's say that the name of the component is TypeComponent and the name of the attribute is productAttribute, the definition of the itemtype TypeComponent is about this:

```
<itemtype code="TypeComponent" extends="SimpleCMSComponent">
     ...
     <attributes>
         <attribute qualifier="productAttribute" type="Product">
             <persistence type="property" />
             <description>Attribute of type Product</description>
             <modifiers read="true" write="true" />
         </attribute>
     </attributes>
 </itemtype>
```

I tried to apply the following according to the official guide, but it didn't work:

```
<bean class="de.hybris.platform.cmsfacades.types.service.impl.DefaultComponentTypeAttributeStructure" p:typecode="TypeComponent" p:qualifier="productAttribute">
     <property name="populators">
         <set>
             <ref bean="productTypeAttributePopulator" />
         </set>
     </property>
</bean>
```

Applying the code above only attribute name label is visible, without any possible iteration. I also tried to use `multiProductSelectorPopulator` as populator and the **+Add Product** button appears and hit it I can also choose the catalog version, but no product is found from Product selection box.

I also tried the one above together with this populator `productCatalogVersionsSelectorPopulator`, but it behaves like in the case of `productTypeAttributePopulator` above.

Do you have any corrections to display the widget correctly for this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that's a known bug.

The attribute name has to be `product` (instead of `productAttribute`) to be editable in smartedit.

Comment: Had the same issue and this worked for me :)